# Hibernate Validator - Compare two Dates - Class-Level constraint

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations, hibernate-validator

So I have to compare two date as mentionned, and i coded a validator and it seems that it has some errors and it's a bit strange : 
Annotation class : Here the @Target annotation is imported but the enum inside is not recognized.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { ValidAfterDateValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface ValidAfterDate {


String message() default "The End date should be after the starting date." ;

Class<?>[] groups() default { };

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

ValidAfterDateValidator.class :

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import gestionprojet.java.entities.Project;

public class ValidAfterDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidAfterDate, Project> {

@Override
public void initialize(ValidAfterDate constraintAnnotation) {
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Project projet, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (projet == null) {
        return true;
    }

    return projet.getDate_Debut().compareTo(projet.getDate_Fin()) > 0;
}
```

And here the @ValidAferDate is disallowed :

Project.class :

```
@ValidAfterDate
public class Project {

 @Future
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/YY")
 private Date date_Debut;

 @Future
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/YY")
 private Date date_Fin;
 //Getters & Setters
 }
```

Any help would appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This :

```
@Target( { TYPE , ANNOTATION_TYPE })
```

needs to be changed to :

```
@Target( {ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.TYPE })
```

and the imporation is :

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
```